Questions on basic k-combination of n-element
So I learn that by definition, $n\choose k$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of some $n$-element set.
However, $n\choose k$ can also be applied to problems like, how many distinct sequences can be made from using $l$ "A"s and $k$ "B"s. So the answer to this type of question, according to my book is:
$$ l+k \choose l$$
And the logic is to think of filling $l+k$ many spaces with $l$ "A"s, so I can get to an answer, but the method makes no sense to me whatsoever.
I like to think in terms of definition, but I don't see how this problem is asking me to find the number of $l$-element subsets from a $l+k$ set.
Could someone point this out? Thanks!

For each subset of size $l$, create a sequence by putting A in those spaces and put B everywhere else.

@Wei I see, but in this case what would be my l+k set ?

The set of all spaces which are to be filled with either A or B.

Let's think about the positions in the sequence. We can number them from 1 to $l + k$. Out of these positions, we want to choose $l$ of them to place "A"s. The remaining $k$ positions will uniquely be filled with "B"s.
This is indeed a subset problem: The "set" you are considering is the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, l + k\}$ of all positions, from which we are selecting a subset of size $l$, i.e., the subset of positions in which we will place "A"s.
Thus, in terms of definition, you should feel comfortable seeing that the answer to the problem is given by $\binom{l+k}{l}$.
